# List of tags with attribute type="submit" in HTML5

Tags: html, types, tags

I need a list of tags with the specific attribute `type="submit"`. The ones I know are `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit">`.Are there any others in HTML5?

Comment: You can checkout [Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other elements with type="submit" than what you mentioned

But note:

- `<input type="image"` is a submit button
- button without a type is default a submit button
- a single text input in a form will submit the form on enter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! :)